# capistrano setup in ubuntu 14.04 conflicts

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04, capistrano

I try setup capristrano deployment - but have errors,

Environment is Ubuntu 14.04

ruby : 
 ruby -v
ruby 2.2.6p396 (2016-11-15 revision 56800) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

```
gem install capistrano
Successfully installed capistrano-3.7.2
Parsing documentation for capistrano-3.7.2
Done installing documentation for capistrano after 1 seconds
1 gem installed



root@grek-Inspiron-11-3147:/tmp# gem install capifony
Successfully installed capifony-2.8.6
Parsing documentation for capifony-2.8.6
Done installing documentation for capifony after 1 seconds
1 gem installed

capifony .
[skip] './Capfile' already exists
[skip] './app/config/deploy.rb' already exists
[done] symfony 2 project capifonied!
```

i setup params.

then

```
cap deploy:setup
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
Gem::ConflictError: Unable to activate capifony-2.8.6, because capistrano-3.7.2 conflicts with capistrano (<= 2.16.0, >= 2.13.5)
/home/grek/PhpstormProjects/osiedle/Capfile:3:in `<top (required)>'
Gem::ConflictError: Unable to activate capifony-2.8.6, because capistrano-3.7.2 conflicts with capistrano (<= 2.16.0, >= 2.13.5)
/home/grek/PhpstormProjects/osiedle/Capfile:3:in `<top (required)>'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- capifony_symfony2
/home/grek/PhpstormProjects/osiedle/Capfile:3:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

How i resolve this errors ?

Answer (score 2):

The error message explains the problem:

```
capistrano-3.7.2 conflicts with capistrano (<= 2.16.0, >= 2.13.5)
```

In other words, capifony apparently requires capistrano <= 2.16.0, >= 2.13.5, but you have installed capistrano 3.7.2.

The solution is to uninstall capistrano and re-install a compatible version.

```
gem uninstall capistrano
gem install capistrano -v "<= 2.16.0, >= 2.13.5"
```

You should see:

```
Fetching: capistrano-2.15.9.gem (100%)
Successfully installed capistrano-2.15.9
1 gem installed
```